# Cordova camera, can't get photo just taken

Tags: android, cordova, camera

i'm building a cordova application, but i can't get the camera to work properly.

My intention is to take a picture, display it and eventually save it.
Here's my code:

JS

```
 67 <script>
 68 var sPicData; //store image data for image upload functionality
 69
 70 function capturePhoto(){
 71     navigator.camera.getPicture(picOnSuccess, picOnFailure, {
 72         quality: 20,
 73         destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
 74         sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
 75         correctOrientation: true
 76     });
 77 }
 78
 79 function getPhoto(){
 80     //navigator.camera.getPicture(picOnSuccess, picOnFailure, {
 81     //    quality: 20,
 82     //    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
 83     //    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM,
 84     //    correctOrientation: true
 85     //});
 86     navigator.camera.getPicture(picOnSuccess, picOnFailure, {
 87         quality: 20
 88     });
 89 }
 90
 91 function picOnSuccess(imageData){
 92         var image = document.getElementById('cameraPic');
 93         alert(image);
 94         image.style.dispay = 'block';
 95         image.src = imageData;
 96         sPicData  = imageData; //store image data in a variable
 97 }
 98
 99 function picOnFailure(message){
100     alert('Failed because: ' + message);
101 }
102 </script>
```

HTML

```
 44 <div id="camera">
 45     <button class="camera-control" onclick="capturePhoto();">Foto aufnehmen</button>
 46     <button class="camera-control" onclick="getPhoto();">From Photo Library</button><br>
 47
 48     <div style="text-align:center;margin:20px;">
 49         <img id="cameraPic" src="" style="width:auto;height:120px;"></img>
 50     </div>
 51
 52     <button class="camera-control" onclick="photoUpload();">UPLOAD</button>
 53 </div>
```

The result is that i can take the photo, but the resulting div is the following:

```
<img id="cameraPic" src="/9j/lots_of_non_sense_stuff///Z" style="width:auto;height:120px;">
```

with this error on that line:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDACgcHiMeGSgjISMtKygwPGRBPDc3PHtYXUlk…ACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigD//Z
```

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image data is returned in base64 format. To display it correctly, you have to tell the browser that the image source is not a file, but base64-encoded data:

```
function picOnSuccess(imageData){
         var image = document.getElementById('cameraPic');
         alert(image);
         image.style.dispay = 'block';
         image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
         sPicData  = imageData; //store image data in a variable
}
```

Another solution would be to let cordova save the picture to a file:

```
function capturePhoto(){
     navigator.camera.getPicture(picOnSuccess, picOnFailure, {
         quality: 20,
         destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
         sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
         correctOrientation: true
     });
}
```

With this approach the success function is called with the path to a temporary file in its imageData parameter so that you can use the code you had before. See documentation:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_camera_camera.md.html

Comment: Sorry i just saw your edited answer, how can i save or display the picture if i let cordova save it with your code?